# How to get rid of duplicate entries in a comma separated string in java?

Tags: java

I have a string places="city,city,town". I need to get "city,town". Basically get rid of duplicate entries in the comma separated string.

places.split(","); will give me array of String. I wonder, if I can pass this array to a HashSet or something, which will automatically get rid of duplicates, but trying something like:

```
HashSet test=new HashSet(a.split(","));
```

gives the error:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol : constructor HashSet(java.lang.String[])
```

Any neat way of achieving this, preferably with least amount of code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
    HashSet<String> test=new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(s.split(",")));
```

this is because [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) does not have a constructor that expects an array. It expects a collection, which is what I am doing here by `Arrays.asList(s.split(","))`

Comment: thanks. works. any quick way to achieve the join thing? i.e. to join hashset entries by ,

Comment: alas, only if you would've asked this question in Python, or Scala. In Java, it's `String finalString = "";for(String s: test)finalString = finalString +s+",";if(finalString.length()>0) finalString = finalString.substring(0, finalString.length()-1);`

Comment: String newTagVals = StringUtils.join(test.toArray(), COMMA);

Answer (score 3):

If you care about the ordering I'd suggest you use a `LinkedHashSet`.

```
LinkedHashSet test = new LinkedHashSet(Arrays.asList(a.split(",")));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String s[] = places.split(",");
HashSet<String> hs = new HashSet<String>();
for(String place:s)
    hs.add(place);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing this in Java 8 would be:

Lets say you have a string *str* which is having some comma separated values in it. You can convert it into stream and remove duplicates and join back into comma separated values as given below:

```
String str = "1,2,4,5,3,7,5,3,3,8";
str = String.join(",",Arrays.asList(str.split(",")).stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

This will give you a String *str* without any duplicate

Answer (score 0):

```
 String[] functions= commaSeperatedString.split(",");

            List<String> uniqueFunctions = new ArrayList<>();

            for (String function : functions) {
                if ( !uniqueFunctions.contains(function.trim())) {
                    uniqueFunctions.add(function.trim());
                }
            }
            return String.join(",",uniqueFunctions);
```

or you can use linkedHashset

LinkedHashSet result = new LinkedHashSet(Arrays.asList(functions.split(",")));

Answer (score 0):

It is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59646261/2682494) and slightly better readability.
Just splitting the string with comma which returns Array of strings and find the distinct values in the array and join the elements using comma, which returns a string without duplicate values.

```
String noDups = Arrays.stream(input.split(",")).distinct().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Comment: I recommend that you don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Also, your answer is very similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59646261/466862), except yours is joining directly from the stream, instead of first converting to a list.